# How to prevent ListTile from switching position when quantity is adjusted in cart?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview

I'm working on a Flutter app where users can add products to their cart, and I'm displaying the cart items in a ListView. Each item in the cart is grouped by product name, and I've provided buttons to adjust the quantity of each product.

However, I'm facing an issue where the order of items in the ListView changes after adjusting the quantities. For instance, if I have two unique products with quantities of 2 and 2 respectively, and I reduce the quantity of the first product from 2 to 1, the second product drops below the first one.

I want to maintain the original order of items in the ListView even after adjusting the quantities. How can I achieve this?

```
class CartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CartPage> createState() => _CartPageState();
}

class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
  void removeFromCart(ImageDetails imageDetails, BuildContext context) {
    final shop = context.read<Shop>();
    shop.removeFromCart(imageDetails);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Shop>(
      builder: (context, shop, child) {
        Map<String, List<ImageDetails>> groupedItems = {};

        // Group items by product name
        for (var item in shop.cart) {
          if (groupedItems.containsKey(item.title)) {
            groupedItems[item.title]!.add(item);
          } else {
            groupedItems[item.title] = [item];
          }
        }

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('My Cart'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: groupedItems.entries.map((entry) {
                    final List<ImageDetails> groupedItems = entry.value;
                    final totalQuantity = groupedItems.length;
                    final productPrice = groupedItems[0].price;

                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(entry.key),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (totalQuantity > 1) {
                                      shop.removeFromCart(groupedItems[0]);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                                ),
                                Text('QTY: $totalQuantity'),
                                IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    shop.addToCart(groupedItems[0], 1);
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(productPrice),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            for (var item in groupedItems) {
                              shop.removeFromCart(item);
                            }
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Pay Now',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put groupedItems in your builder which means you're re-declaring variable named groupedItems every time a rebuild is triggered. groupedItems seems to be your main source of data which is consumed by your tree.

move groupedItems outside of builder

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Shop>(
      builder: (context, shop, child) {
        Map<String, List<ImageDetails>> groupedItems = {};

..... }
```

to

```
Map<String, List<ImageDetails>> groupedItems = {};

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Shop>(
      builder: (context, shop, child) {

..... }
```

Comment: Didn't work, and causes the add to multiply instead.